# Zookeeper gotcha with ephemeral nodes

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

[Zookeeper Gotcha blog post](https://www.box.com/blog/a-gotcha-when-using-zookeeper-ephemeral-nodes/)

This blog post refers to "sessions". Does it mean Zookeeper client sessions (like the ones you make in Java to interface with the server) or does session refer to the zookeeper server itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue refers to ZooKeeper sessions tracked by the server, the same one you would specify with session timeout when creating the client.